# Futurebuilder does not work properly with sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart

**I am trying to insert new task into the database but when I go back to the home screen nothing is updated and I should hot reload to see the changes do you have any idea why is happening ?

I tried several things but the problem is still occurring. Please if you need more details let me know. Thanks!
**

```
´import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:todo_task/models/Task.dart';
    import 'package:todo_task/utils/Helper.dart';
    import 'package:todo_task/widgets/reusable_card.dart';

    class TaskList extends StatefulWidget {
      final String status;

      const TaskList({this.status});

      @override
      _TaskListState createState() => _TaskListState();
    }

    class _TaskListState extends State<TaskList> {

      final Helper helper = Helper();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder<List<Task>>(
            future: helper.getTasks(widget.status),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Task>> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError)
                    return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                  else
                    return Column(
                      children: snapshot.data
                          .map((task) => ReusableCard(
                                task: task,
                              ))
                          .toList(),
                    );
              }
            });
      }
    }




    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:todo_task/widgets/custom_date.dart';
    import 'package:todo_task/widgets/new_task.dart';
    import 'package:todo_task/widgets/task_list.dart';

    import '../constants.dart';

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

      @override
      void initState() { 
        super.initState();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(28.0, 20.0, 28.0, 20.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CustomDate(),
                      NewTask(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    'TODO TASKS',
                    style: kAppTitleTextStyle,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  TaskList(status: 'uncompleted',),
                  Divider(),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    'DONE TASKS',
                    style: kAppTitleTextStyle,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  TaskList(status: 'completed',),
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }´
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update the database you are basically updating a file in your device, and that will not Hot Reload. What you should do is, when the DB operation is finished, update the Future that gets the tasks.

Also, note that is best practice to save the Future instance you use in the FutureBuilder in the State, that way you can do:

```
setState((){
    this.tasksFuture = helper.getTasks(widget.status);
});
```

Comment: are you calling getTasks (updating the future as shown above) again after you await the insert operation? Also remember to replace the future in the FutureBuilder with the future in the State class.